# Jquery toggle fade and animate

Tags: jquery

I use a toggle button to show/hide content o my page. And my goal is to toggle the content from the #circleBtn,
But I want the #logo to "toggle up" and fade out and the #content div to toggle left and fade out when togggle.. Right now everything just fades..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#circleBtn").click(function() { 
            $('#logo,#access,#content').fadeToggle('easeInElastic');
        });

        $("#logo").click(function () {
            $("#content").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no built in jQuery methods that slides an element up or sideways and at the same time fades it out, but using the `animate()` method you can animate anything you'd like, and to make it toggle, you can use a flag

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#circleBtn").on('click', function() { 
        var flag = $(this).data('flag');

        $('#logo, #access, #content').animate({
            top     : (flag ? -100 : 0),
            opacity : (flag ? 0 : 1)
        }, 1000, 'easeInElastic');

        $(this).data('flag', !flag);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7EXz7/)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you wouldn't want to put all of the code that toggles and fades your HTML elements in the circleBtn click listener function?

Like this:

```
$("#circleBtn").click(function() { 
   $("#content").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
   $("#logo").show("slide", {direction: "up" },1000);
   $('#logo,#access,#content').fadeToggle('easeInElastic');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using jquery,animate instead since it appears you want a custom animation.

try:

```
$('#logo').animate({
  opacity:0,
  height: 0
});

$('#content').animate({
  opacity:0,
  width: 0
});
```

You can do the reverse to show them